# android studio run programs

Tags: android, android-studio

I try an android studio. It is ok at the beginning. When I do a activity with many java content, it cannot run the program. It has the below error:

```
Gradle: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ImageCropper:compileDebug'.

Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
```

After I comment the code it is ok. There is no problem with code. How to deal with this?

Comment: Android Studio is a preview, expect bugs

Comment: It would help to know more about the code that doesn't compile. For instance is it referencing external libraries, and if yes, how to did you add dependencies on those libraries.